# R ColProds and minimum of a column of a matrix

Tags: r, matrix, product, min, col

I have this diff_rc matrix:

> diff_rc

```
      [,1]         [,2]         [,3]
 [1,]    1  0.043131541  0.079957068
 [2,]    2  0.079957068  0.074712332
 [3,]    3  0.074712332  0.041978947
 [4,]    4  0.041978947 -0.003661470
 [5,]    5 -0.003661470 -0.047627302
 [6,]    6 -0.047627302 -0.077841351
 [7,]    7 -0.077841351 -0.092244072
 [8,]    8 -0.092244072 -0.091280341
 [9,]    9 -0.091280341 -0.075395031
[10,]   10 -0.075395031 -0.045033013
[11,]   11 -0.045033013 -0.003151946
[12,]   12 -0.003151946  0.037239385
[13,]   13  0.037239385  0.060619410
[14,]   14  0.060619410  0.051466559
[15,]   15  0.051466559 -0.005740738
```

I have created this code for checking the change of signs fro the raws.

```
x_loc <- red_curve$x[diff_rc[which(rowProds(diff_rc[, 2:3]) < 0), 1]] #return index "index"
y_loc <- red_curve$y[diff_rc[which(rowProds(diff_rc[, 2:3]) < 0), 1]]
```

These are the results

```
[1]  4 12 15
> y_loc
[1]  0.041978947 -0.003151946  0.051466559
> diff_rc
```

1- My problem is that I would like to check where the sign changes in column [,2]. For example the sign changes from 4 to 5 and from 12 to 13 It went from +ve to -ve or vice versa. only on the second column. I tried this code but doesn't work for the matrix

```
> colProds(diff_rc[,2])
Error in double(length = n) : invalid 'length' argument
In addition: Warning message:
Argument 'x' is of class ‘numeric’, but should be a matrix. The use of a ‘numeric’ is not supported, the correctness of the result is not guaranteed, and will be defunct (produce an error) in a future version of matrixStats. Please update your code according
```

2- After checking the change of the sign, I need to return the minimum value of the two elements. e.g (-0.003661470) should be the returned value from column 4 and 5

Comment: You need to make sure you're not dropping the matrix dimensions, i.e. use `colProds(diff_rc[,2, drop=FALSE])`.

Comment: >numeric(0)
Is there a way to ignore first and last indices?

Answer (score 0):

Replace `a` with `diff_rc[,2]`

```
a <- runif(10, -10, 10)

ind <- which(sign(a) != lag(sign(a)))

pairs <- sapply(ind, function(x) a[c(x, x - 1)])

rbind(index = ind, min.val = apply(pairs, 2, min), pairs)
#               [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]
# index    2.0000000  4.000000  5.000000  9.000000 10.000000
# min.val -3.8646299 -1.461847 -8.297281 -4.553899 -1.406569
#         -3.8646299  3.862042 -8.297281  2.316586 -1.406569
#          0.1495641 -1.461847  3.862042 -4.553899  2.316586
```

Comment: This is what I get. I replaced runif(10, -10,10) with diff_rc[,2]
> ind
integer(0)
> pairs
list()

Comment: I guess I didn't consider that this method is expecting a vector, not a dataframe. You can do `a <- unlist(diff_rc[,2])`.

Comment: same in addition: Error in apply(pairs, 2, min) : dim(X) must have a positive length. What if I use colProds and ignore first and last raw on the list. Is there a way to do that?